# Cannot open sparsebundle to review Backups.backupdb

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, macos, time-capsule

I'm trying to open the Backups.backupdb folder and when I try to open the sparse bundle I get the following error message.

> The application "DiskImageMounter.app" can't be opened. -36

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

First, disable Time Machine backup. Then Try this: https://blog.davekoelmeyer.co.nz/2011/03/03/browse-a-time-capsule-disk-image-in-the-mac-os-finder/

Comment: link-only answers don't last long on this site. Feel free to copy/paste the essence of the possible solution from the site you link to into the answer itself. The `hdiutil` terminal command may just do the trick.